# Per executable UDP port redirection possible?

Tags: linux, networking, port, redirection

I have a black box program which listens on a particular UDP port. I'd like it to listen to a UDP port of my choosing.

Is there a way to trick the executable into listening on a differen port. I might imagine there exists a library which could be injected with LD_PRELOAD that might incercept the system calls and facilitate this.

A virtual machine of course is the heavy handed option.

Answer (score 2):

You could use iptables to forward one port to another. That will only work for outside connections, because nat tables which the following solution uses aren't consulted when traffic is local (ie. from 127.0.0.1 to 127.0.0.1 and so on and so forth).

This also requires you to enable forwarding in your kernel which may or may not be a security issue you don't want to face.

Begin by turning on forwarding, if it already isn't with either `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` or `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`. In this case you probably should also make all iptables policies to be DROP instead of default ACCEPT (this depends on the GNU/Linux distribution you use, though) and allow just the traffic you'd like to get through instead of letting everything flow freely.

Then you can add a rule to nat PREROUTING table to redirect traffic destined to port X to port Y. For example to redirect incoming traffic to TCP port 2222 to your SSH server port, TCP 22, use this: `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 2222 -j REDIRECT --to-port 22`.

More information about port redirection and finer points of are available from various search enginer and for example [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/port-mapping-with-iptables-781036/).

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is to use netcat. It works also with connections with localhost, and there is no need to change sysctl.

The whole trick is to create a `named pipe`,

```
 mkfifo mypipe
```

and use it like this:

```
nc -k -l 2222 0<mypipe | nc localhost mySSHport 1>mypipe
```

This example has been created to allow you to test this command with ssh. It redirects ssh connections from port 2222 to port mySSHport, whatever that may be (22?).

Now if you try to ssh into port 2222,

```
 ssh me@localhost -p 2222
```

you will be logged in.

The flag `-k` instructs netcat to keep listening even after completion of first connection. You can improve its resilience by inserting it into an infinite while loop:

```
while true; do
# echo "Listening..."
nc -k -l 2222 0<mypipe | nc localhost mySSHport 1>mypipe
done
```

And of course, going back to the OP, for UDP ports one has to add the -u flag.

Edit:

I just realized that on systems running the GNU version of nc (netcat) like Arch Linux, the command should be

```
 nc -l -p 2222 0<mypipe | nc localhost mySSHport 1>mypipe
```

Apologies for the inconveniece.